# How gitub webhooks works?

Tags: github

How the *github webhooks* works, and how would it know which build needs to trigger based on the events.

I have an public git repository and in which have configured the *jenkins webhooks* which triggers build on the every push event.

**Payload URL**: http:///github-webhook/

**Content Type**: www-form-urlencoded

**Event**: Push

How the Payload URL identifies the right build job to trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can using "Generic Webhook Trigger" or "Trigger Builds Remotely" Plugin and specify token on your jenkins job. Pass your jenkins server url (with token you have specified) on github webhook payload url